# Blazor error: The hash algorithm must be one of 'sha256', 'sha384', or 'sha512', followed by a '-' character

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

My Blazor WebAssembly standalone (not hosted) app works fine locally running in Visual Studio but when I deploy to a Windows server - IIS the app doesn't load within the browser and this is showing in the console:
[image]

I also see in the network panel it is making a request to the server for:
https://{myDomain}/_framework/undefined
A file that doesn't exist, so it's just returning the index.html content.

I have tried deleting everything and deploying a 2nd time and also tried restarting the website in IIS but it doesn't help.

Comment: Perhaps try "npx serve" from your "wwwroot" folder instead of using IIS just to see whether it's a problem with your project specifically or with something IIS is doing. You might also try a different browser. If it fails the same when hosted differently and when using different browsers, at least you'll be sure it's a problem with your stuff.

Answer (score 4):

So I found the problem, in Visual Studio when you publish the Blazor app I had Target Runtime set as Win-x64, when I changed it to **browser-wasm** everything is OK.

Comment: It is this sort of crap from Microsoft that has caused me to drop Blazor as something to learn. They claim it is cross platform yet they can't even get it to cross form IIS Express to IIS on the same PC. I am a C# programmer but when it comes to web I'll stick to something that works!

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is not "Target Framework" it's "Target Runtime".
[image]

You confused me for a bit. This is why I'm posting. If you have a time please update your post, for others. Thank you. Your post helped me.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my original post so it says Target Runtime now.